# What ECMAScript version does Node.js support?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've searched the Node.js documentation, but I can't find what version is supported.

Comment: Usually ECMAScript support is on a per-feature basis. Which _feature_ do you need to support? Use https://caniuse.com/ and MDN to find if Node.js supports that feature.

Comment: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/es6/ Also note, that this page links to https://node.green/ which shows the individual status of specific features

Comment: ES2022 is 100% supported in the current LTS. The built against Chrome's V8, so whatever Chrome supports, they will likely support as well

Answer (score 23):

JS engines don't generally announce support for specific versions of the specification. Instead they support specific features.

There are websites which track support, such as [this one](https://compat-table.github.io/compat-table/es2016plus/) which shows Node.js 16+ as supporting up to ES2022.

Comment: Thanks. "JS engines don't generally announce support for specific versions of the specification." That seems....less than useful. "What version of HTTP do you use?" "Well, let me tell you a story......"

Comment: @PaulDraper Yes? https://caniuse.com/cors shows partial support for the CORS bit of HTTP in some versions of some browsers.

Comment: CORS is W3C (World Wide Web) not HTTP, but I understand.

Comment: @PaulDraper — That's like saying The Highway Code is the Government and not Road Usage.